# How to modify the distances returned by knn in R?

Tags: r

I have the following code with uses the [FNN Package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/index.html):

```
k <- knn(train, test, labels, k = 10, algorithm="cover_tree")
```

I am able to look at the data returned by the call to knn using the code below:

```
> attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,]
 [1] 1385.398 1687.901 1722.884 1846.694 1978.250 1998.157 2003.518 2004.494 2054.382 2059.128
> attr(k, "nn.index")[1,]
 [1] 983 362 170 303 914 843 480 489 474 355
```

What I would like to do is modify the values that are in `nn.dist` based on the values that are in `nn.index`.

I know this probably doesn't make sense, but for the sake of argument, how would I go about setting each value in `nn.dist` to `nn.dist * nn.index/1000`?

So `attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,1]` would go from `1385.398` to `1385.398*983/1000` (1361.846)

and
`attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,2]` would go from `1687.901` to `1687.901*362/1000` (611.02) etc.

I am able to do this one at a time with the following code:

```
attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,1] = attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,1]*attr(k, "nn.index")[1,1]/1000
```

But I need a way to do this to every element, without writing it every time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic operators `*`, `+`, `/` and `-` are vectorised and will work elementwise on an array.

Therefore it is as easy as

```
attr(k, "nn.dist") * attr(k, "nn.index") /1000
```

If you only want to do this to the first row of `nn.dist`, then

```
attr(k, "nn.dist")[1,]* attr(k, "nn.index")[1,] /1000
```

You could reassign to the `nn.dist` attribute of `k`, but I would suggest copying to ensure that you know that it is not the original output eg

```
k_adj <- k
attr(k_adj, "nn.dist") <- attr(k_adj, "nn.dist") * attr(k_adj, "nn.index") /1000
```

or you could simply add a new attribute to the original

```
 attr(k, 'nn.dist.adj') <- attr(k, "nn.dist") * attr(k, "nn.index") /1000
```